# Where does HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name get stored / accessed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

On our intranet pages, we're checking who the user is and displaying it on the site as a label.  For all other users the logged in name is correct. For this user it shows as OURDOMAIN\ADMINISTRATOR.

I know HOW it happened.  One day there was an issue with permissions and I launched the page from her PC.  IE prompted for the user, and rejected her login.  I tried using the domain admin, and it let us access the page, but now I can't get it back to her login.  It's not browser specific, as I installed Chrome and get the same behavior.

The page connects to the database (using SQL Authentication), and then runs a stored procedure.  After that, the following code is run:

```
string userid = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
lbl_User.Text = userid;
```

How / Where do I reset this for her?  Is XP or IIS that cached these credentials?

Comment: maybe try rebooting the computer and restarting IIS.

Comment: The PC has been rebooted, all cache has been cleared, IIS has been restarted numerous times since.  Not only has IIS been restarted, but that server has been rebooted a few times.

Comment: I found the solution:  the page was in the "Intranet" zone.  I opened IE, and went into internet options.  I went to the Internet Options, went to security tab, selected Intranet, and then "Custom Level".  Went down to user authentication and set it to "Prompt for user name and password".  Closed the browser, reopened that page and then it prompted me.  Changed the credentials accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: the page was in the "Intranet" zone. I opened IE, and went into internet options. I went to the Internet Options, went to security tab, selected Intranet, and then "Custom Level". Went down to user authentication and set it to "Prompt for user name and password". Closed the browser, reopened that page and then it prompted me. Changed the credentials accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely stored in Managed Passwords:

- Click Start > Run
- Enter "control userpasswords2"
- Click the Advanced tab
- Click Manage Passwords
- Select the wrong credentials
- Click Remove

You may need to log-off and back on again for these setting to change.

This is definitely a problem with the client PC and not IIS. Windows stores credentials for later use and will automatically send these to the web server via the browser.

Comment: It is empty. No passwords are stored there on this system.